# Get domain name expiration

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to take a list of domain names we have and email a report when they expire.

I found this script but can't find why it doesn't work. Says it's missing a closing bracket but I'm not seeing it.

```
function WhoIs {
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            HelpMessage='Please enter domain name (e.g. microsoft.com)'
        )]
        [string]$domain
    )
    Write-Host "Connecting to Web Services URL..." -ForegroundColor Green
    try {
        if ($whois = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://www.webservicex.net/whois.asmx?WSDL") {
            Write-Host "Ok" -ForegroundColor Green
        } else {
            Write-Host "Error" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        Write-Host "Gathering $domain data..." -ForegroundColor Green
        (($Whois.getwhois($domain)).Split("<<<")[0])
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Please enter valid domain name (e.g. microsoft.com)." -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

```
New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
At line:9 char:14
+ ... f ($whois = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "webservicex.net/whoi ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (webs...whois.asmx?WSDL:Uri) [New-WebServiceProxy], WebException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
```

Comment: There has to be an easy way to get this info.

Comment: The error message is rather clear: the page you requested doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I agree does anyone one else know of a site I can use?

Comment: I found this other powershell script that will return the whois information. https://github.com/bone187/PowerShell-Whois/blob/master/whois.ps1